# DataGrid с RadioButton. Выбор в RadioButton привязать к внешнему свойству?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, radiobutton

Имеется DataGrid с RadioButton-нами:

[image: пример]

Необходимо устанавливать необходимый RadioButton в соответствии со свойством SelectedParam при загрузке. И менять его при смене выбора RadioButton.

Подскажите как сделать такую привязку?

```
public class MainVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Param> ParamList { get; }
    public Param SelectedParam { get; set; }
}

public class Param {
    string Name  { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ParamList}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton GroupName="RadioButtonGroup"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: С помощью конвертера

Comment: @Андрей NOP А можно чуть подробнее алгоритм описать?

Comment: Да, вам нужен конвертер (мультиконвертер), который будет сравнивать 2 экземпляра класса `Param` и возвращать `true` если они равны (ссылка на один и тот же экземпляр). В конвертер передаете `SelectedParam` (`{Binding DataContext.SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}`) и текущий элемент привязанный к строке (`{Binding}`)

Comment: @Андрей Спасибо за ответ. Сделал как вы сказали IMultiValueConverter. При помощи MultiBinding привязал два параметра. Но не понимаю как сделать ConvertBack?

Comment: Ага, ConvertBack видимо здесь не получится сделать. Делайте одностороннюю привязку, а для установки SelectedParam делайте команду и привязывайте ее к RadioButton'ам, `{Binding}` передавайте параметром в команду